# GAS - If a condition is false wait until is true to continue

Tags: google-apps-script

im newbie and i need help. Im creating a bot for my job on google sheetd with app script.
I hve this right now:

````
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('F5');
  range.check();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G5").getValue() == "OK") {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('F6')
  range.check()
  }
}```

The process is simply, when i click a button the script changes the checkbox in f5 to true, then, if G5 says OK, change the next checkbox in f6 to true.
I need to make the script wait until g5 says OK...
Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Do you know there's a timeout of 6 minutes in apps script?

Comment: What process causes G5 to say OK?  Is that triggered by checking F5?